# Get a list of all my comments?

Tags: support, comments

In my profile page there is a tab to see

- all my questions
- all my answers
- badges .... etc.

but there is no way to see all my comments?

I sometime find that I leave a comment on some question, only to think of a better comment or some answer I suddenly got in the shower .. but then I cannot find the question again.

Is there a way to get the questions/answers for which you have commented?

Assuming "no" -- so is there a reason for why that feature does not exists?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is an easy way to see your comments.

Go to your profile.

Click on ***Activity***

Click on ***Comments***

Here's a link to it https://stackoverflow.com/users/668501/soren?tab=activity&sort=comments

Comment: You are absolutely right... Thanks.